# jqGrid creating separate function

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

How can I seperate `function subGridRowExpanded` to another function and cast to `subGridRowExpanded :` .

```
subGrid: Hierarchy,

subGridOptions : {
   plusicon : "ace-icon fa fa-plus center bigger-110 blue",
   minusicon  : "ace-icon fa fa-minus center bigger-110 blue",
   openicon : "ace-icon fa fa-chevron-right center orange" }, 
subGridRowExpanded: function subGridRowExpanded(subgrid_id, row_id) 
{ 
   //somecode
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand correctly your question. I suppose that you don't want use *anonymous* function as the value of `subGridRowExpanded`. In the case you have two standard ways in JavaScript:

1) define variable and assign anonymous function to it.

```js
var mySubGridRowExpanded = function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
        // here one can use 'this' to access to the grid
        // for example
        //
        // var mainGridPrefix = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
        //     pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId);

        // create empty table and div with unique ids which we construct base on
        // id of subgrid div created by jqGrid before calling of mySubGridRowExpanded
        var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>" +
                         "<div id='" + subgridDivId + "_p" + "'></div>");

        // append the subgrid to the subgrid div
        $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));

        // create subgrid as jqGrid
        $subgrid.jqGrid({
            ...
        });
    };
```

2) define named `function` like you know in other computer languages. One use the terminology [*function statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) in Javascript for the case. The previous way (with `var mySubGridRowExpanded = function (subgridDivId, rowId) {...};`) one names [*function expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). You can use the name of such function as the value of `subGridRowExpanded` property of jqGrid.

```js
function mySubGridRowExpanded (subgridDivId, rowId) {
    // the same code as above with small disadvantage
    // that one could have warnings by some JavaScript
    // validators that 'this' could be undefined.
}
```

In both cases you can just use jqGrid options like

```
subGrid: true,
subGridOptions : {
    plusicon : "ace-icon fa fa-plus center bigger-110 blue",
    minusicon  : "ace-icon fa fa-minus center bigger-110 blue",
    openicon : "ace-icon fa fa-chevron-right center orange" }, 
subGridRowExpanded: mySubGridRowExpanded
```

JavaScript have another semantic of functions as I know in my favorite languages because of the ways how one can define classes and objects. So I personally prefer the first way (function expression) of definition `mySubGridRowExpanded` function (`var mySubGridRowExpanded = function (subgridDivId, rowId) {...};`)